# Selecting specific records in a column else all of them

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am building a website in ASP.NET/ SQL Server 2012.

My question is, I have drop down boxes that contain the following strings as an example.

```
<asp:ListItem>Doesn't matter</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>I don't drink</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Occasionally/Socially</asp:ListItem>                
<asp:ListItem>I party hard</asp:ListItem>
```

What sort of SQL command do I need to in order to be able to use logic like this pseduo.

```
If SelectedItem is 'Doesn't Matter' return all rows in column
ELSE IF
Retrieve records in column where drinking_habit = ListItem.
```

I dont want to use a simple IF ELSE stored procedure because I have lots and lots of filtering options available and making else seems really badly designed.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WHERE` with `OR`:

```
SELECT IdCol, TextCol
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE @TextCol = 'Doesnt matter' OR TextCol = @TextCol
```

On this way `TextCol` will only be evaluated if the parameter is different than `Doesn't matter`.

Note that i've used the text value just for demonstration purposes. You should use the `IdCol` instead(text can change anyway).

Comment: if you have actually `'` in your value then use this `SELECT IdCol, TextCol
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE @TextCol = 'Doesn''t matter' OR TextCol = @TextCol`

Comment: @Dhaval: That's why i've mentioned explicitely `parameters` and `IdCol`. You could also use a subquery like `.. = (SELECT habit_name FROM dbo.DrinkingHabits WHERE idDrinkingHabit=1)`

Comment: Hey Tim, thank you for your advice. The issue is that there are no records with 'Doesnt Matter' in the column. Its meant to represent the default of 'Select All records from column'

So what I am looking to do is if the user clicks 'Doesnt Matter', all records are retrieved, but none of them have 'Doesnt Matter'.

All records in th database will have either of these three values.


I don't drink OR
Occasionally/Socially             
OR I party hard

Comment: You havent tried my approach, it does exactly what you want. Note that  i m not comparing the column value with "Doesn't matter" but the parameter you are passing to the command.